# System of coupled PDEs: “Repeated convergence test failure” error

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve the following system of coupled PDEs but I am getting an error.

```
eqns = {D[Z[t, x], t] == W[t, x],
        4*D[U[t, x], {x, 2}] + 4*D[Z[t, x], {x, 2}]*D[W[t, x], x] + 
          4*D[Z[t, x], x]*D[W[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0, 
        -D[W[t, x], {x, 4}]/3 + 4*D[W[t, x], x]*D[Z[t, x], x]*D[Z[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
          4*D[Z[t, x], {x, 2}]*D[U[t, x], x] - 1 == 0};

bc = {U[t, -1] == 0, U[t, 1] == 0, W[t, -1] == 0, W[t, 1] == 0, 
       Derivative[0, 1][W][t, -1] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][W][t, 1] == 0, 
       Z[t, -1] == 0, 
       Z[t, 1] == 0, U[0, x] == 0, Z[0, x] == 0, W[0, x] == -(1 - x^2)^2/8}

NDSolve[{eqns, bc}, {U, W, Z}, {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

In the paper where these equations are taken from, it is mentioned that, to expedite the computation and to preserve the form of the equations, they added the term Re*dW/dt to the left side of third equation (where Re is the Reynold's number) and the term e^2*Re*dU/dt (where e<<1) to the left side of the second equation.

I tried to run the code above but I got the error

> "Repeated convergence test failure at t == 0.000025`; unable to continue".

Could anybody help me please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: A numerical solution is more than enough. I tried indeed with NDSolve but nothing...

Comment: Your boundary conditions should also be expressed as equations using `==`, rather than assignments using `=`. Make sure to restart your kernel to clean out any spurious assigned values before you evaluate the corrected code. If I do that with your code, I do get a result.

Comment: thank you very much. my apologizes for the noob mistake.

Comment: I updated my question as the situation has changed.

Comment: I'm reopening this question. It's not a simple mistake anymore as far as I can see, and I could reproduce the numerical error. Hopefully someone can help you.

Comment: Add  `Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}` to `NDSolve` should help.And Then see solution: `Plot3D[#[t, x] /.% , {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}] & /@ {U, W, Z}`

Comment: thank you very much for your help. it worked!
one last question: is it possible to retrieve the analytical version of the interpolating functions given as output by NDSolve? Thank you again.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Would you consider expanding your comment into an answer? I am unfamiliar with that option and would appreciate learning what it does.

Comment: @MarcoB. No because, I am unfamiliar with that option  to.I do not have that experience like user: `Michael E2` or `halirutan`.I have been using `MMA` for only 3 years.

Comment: @MarcoB, it is related to the solution of differential algebraic equations (DAEs). Only one equation has a time derivative in, so this system is of that form.